# How to rename index column using pandas.read_excel

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read excel file .xls with `read_excel()`, I need to skip first 16 rows, skip footer 38 rows, use only 2,3,4,5 columns, **set second column as index column**, **set 16-th row as header row and rename the header row**. But jupyter returning `Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 4 elements`.

```
excel_file = 'Filename.xls'

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, header = 0, skiprows = 16, skip_footer = 38, usecols = [2,3,4,5], names = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4'], index_col = 0)

df
```

I tried `without index_col=0` it works but set **default index column**, I don't need default index column I need **my column with "Name1" to be the index column**.

Comment: If it is acceptable for you, you can use `df.set_index('Name1', inplace=True)` as a next step after the `read_excel()`. Docs: [set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)